# Como evitar las credenciales de inicio de sesion con selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

estoy haciendo un checker de cuentas (Basicamente prueba las cuentas a ver si logean o no, es para propositos de practica sin más) Tengo todo hecho practicamente y funciona de 10, exceptuando por el momento en el que una cuenta si funciona y logea.
Al logear debe mandar un print y al instante volver a la pagina de inicio de sesión para seguir probando el resto de cuentas, el problema es que vuelve a la pagina de inicio de sesión pero al instante inicia sesión como cuando guardamos una contraseña de una web.

Probé con diferentes methods pero ninguno me ayuda con este problema. Asi que resumidamente la pregunta es Si hay alguna manera de solucionar esto. No sé si sea algo de la pagina como tal o algo que me falte a mi.

Probé lo siguiente:

`options.set_preference("signon.rememberSignons", False`

`options.set_preference("browser.cache.disk.enable", False`

`options.set_preference("browser.cache.memory.enable", False`

`options.set_preference("network.http.use-cache", False`

`driver.delete_all_cookies()`

Comment: ya intentaste borrar los campos cuando regresas? osea... obviamente el desarrollador del sitio puede hacer que se borren pero ya intentaste hacer tu "manualmente" apretando la tecla borrar muchas veces?

Comment: Nono, lo que pasa no es que se autorellenen los campos, literalmente es como los checks que tiene instagram para "Iniciar sesión automaticamente", cosa de que abrís la app y ni te pide usuario. Bueno lo mismo, yo entro a la pagina de inicio de sesión y automaticamente se mete a la cuenta y por lo tanto, cambia de subdominio Dejandome asi inutil el resto del codigo.

Comment: y pasa lo mismo cuando una persona lo prueba? si es que si deberás correr de cero el escenario cerrando el navegador y abriendo uno nuevo

Answer (score 0):

te propongo que evites que Selenium guarde las credenciales de inicio de sesion en las cookies del navegador.

Para hacer eso te dejo el siguiente codigo:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options= Options() #Creas la instancia de Options
options.set_preference("remember_login_credentials", False) #Con esto evitas que se guarden las credenciales en las cookies
```

Despues creas la instancia del navegador con las opciones, pero eso supongo que ya lo tendras hecho, sino `buscador= webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)`

Espero que te ayude. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente parece un problema de la app+navegador, prueba iniciar en incognito y luego cerrar el navegador. Recomiendo borrar las credenciales de esta página que pudieran estar guardadas en el administrador de contraseñas de chrome.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--incognito")  # o sin --
# options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

lista_checker = {}
for i in lista_checker
    driver.get('lapagina.com')
    # prueba si logea y haz el print
    driver.close()  # esto cierra el navegador
driver.quit()  # esto cierra el driver y el navegador
```